# Обновил android studio до 2.3 ошибка

Tags: android, java

Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: E:\android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

при установке антивирус удалил случайно java.exe,но я не уверен помогите решить проблему

Comment: а) Переустановить Android Studio. б) Указать внешний JDK.

Comment: а можно не удаляя переустановить ,как например на microsoft viusal studio

Comment: Можете попробовать накатить сверху, но, как правило, этот метод чреват проблемами. Лучший, в данном случае способ – это clean install.

Comment: исправил ошибку но теперь ,

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb